# azure storage emulator and function - trigger on filename with guid and extension blows -why?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-blob-trigger

This has taken a while to track down.

I have this code that works

```
            CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        var uploadedContainer = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference("uploadedfiles");
        uploadedContainer.CreateIfNotExists(new BlobRequestOptions() { RetryPolicy = new NoRetry() }, null);

        var directory = uploadedContainer.GetDirectoryReference(path);
        CloudBlockBlob cloudBlockBlob = directory.GetBlockBlobReference($"dave.pdf");
```

but if I change the last line to the following my blob trigger blows up in the function

```
CloudBlockBlob cloudBlockBlob = directory.GetBlockBlobReference($"{Guid.NewGuid().ToString()}.pdf");
```

Very frustrating.
The error is :

> [18/10/2019 14:37:36] An unhandled exception has occurred. Host is shutting down.
>   [18/10/2019 14:37:36] Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage: Server encountered an internal error. Please try again after some time.

Great use of error message - thanks!

I want to be able to use a guid here. The docs for naming conventions seem to say this is a legal situation [found here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/rest/api/storageservices/naming-and-referencing-shares--directories--files--and-metadata)

someone must have an idea!

the following filenames work

`"s-a"
"dave.pdf"
$"{Guid.New().ToString()}"`

This does not work
`$"{Guid.New().ToString()}.pdf"`

Comment: Why do you need to use `Path.GetFileName`?

Comment: its there from me trimming down the problem. I have reproduced without it (I have a github issue without it! i just forgot to update here!) sorry

Comment: I have a similar scenario, I have a blob storage that can receive any file name, then it moves to a new one using a new Guid as part of the filename. 

Azure function is abending just like yours, the difference is that it abends with both azure storage emulator and actual Azure Storage blob.

I ended up using half f the guid string and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose it's caused by `Path.GetFileName`, I'm not testing with this method, I just test with the guid and it could work for me. The below is my test code, maybe you could change the `GetBlockBlobReference`.

```
       string storageConnectionString = "connection string";

        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount;

        CloudStorageAccount.TryParse(storageConnectionString, out storageAccount);

        CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

        CloudBlobContainer cloudBlobContainer = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference("test");
        string sourceFile = "C:\\Users\\georgec\\Downloads\\fileshare\\1.txt";

        String Path = "image/";
        var directory = cloudBlobContainer.GetDirectoryReference(Path);

        CloudBlockBlob cloudBlockBlob = directory.GetBlockBlobReference($"{Guid.NewGuid().ToString()}.txt");


        await cloudBlockBlob.UploadFromFileAsync(sourceFile);
```

[image]

Comment: sorry i have tried without that also. It is specifically (as per examples) guid.pdf - updated the question without that code. thanks

Comment: So your error is cause by `Guid.NewGuid().ToString()`?